# network diagram/ flow diagram in JQuery

Tags: jquery, workflow, graph

Have You got any examples or links to free JQuery flow diagram or network/ graph diagram ?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27643/is-there-a-library-for-rendering-basic-flow-diagrams-in-javascript-css

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Wirekit looks good for creating custom wired flows:

http://neyric.github.com/wireit/

Although JSPlumb doesn't have something for explicitly creating flow charts, I'm sure you can get this to work for your purposes.

http://morrisonpitt.com/jsPlumb/html/jquery/demo.html

Comment: Did you try mydiagram.org ? Its far more advanced than jsPlumb and Wirekit and has a dozen of diagram types.

Answer (score 3):

[jGraphUI](http://www.jgraphui.com) is very close to what you need and it's free.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe with some tweaks u could use [jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/)