# embeddable javascript brainstorming tools

Tags: javascript, html, visualization, collaboration, mindmapping

I'm trying to develop a website to do some collaborative brainstorming with my friends. While there are plenty of websites offering mind-mapping services online, I would like to create my own so that we can share files/data while we brainstorm.

So, I am looking for a plugin which I can embed in my HTML page to give us the functionality of a mindmap, which can be tied back to a database on our server. Does such a plugin/or a similar brainstorming/mindmapping plugin exist?

From my research, only promising lead, webofweb.net, does not have a functioning website.

If I cannot find a plugin, I will build the functionality myself. Here are my ideas. I'd appreciate your feedback and suggestions, as I am still an amateur html/javascript programmer.

- Use a javascript tree generator to dynamically organize enteries, display them in a FLARE visualization
- display them in a Jit visualization (thejit.org using the force-directed graph)
- use jqueryui draggables on a grid
- I'd lose the ability to link ideas, but at least similar items could be clustered together

Are there any alternatives I have not considered?

Answer (score 0):

Per [this related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700332/network-diagram-flow-diagram-in-jquery), [wirekit](http://neyric.github.com/wireit/) looks like it might be just what you are looking for.  Can't say I've used it, but the examples are fun to goof around with...